# Using Activex Control with Parameters

Tags: internet-explorer, vb6, activex

I have built an ActiveX control and when I use without parameter it works, it doesn't work when it used with parameters.

```
<OBJECT  classid="clsid:959B7E21-5C0B-4BEC-BA2E-48DA2B6D66C8"></OBJECT>
```

It doesn't load in IE when I use as follows, nothing is displayed.

```
<OBJECT  classid="clsid:959B7E21-5C0B-4BEC-BA2E-48DA2B6D66C8">                
            <PARAM NAME="Id" VALUE="2">
</OBJECT>
```

Also I am receiving this warning

[image]

In my control code I have defined the property for the control as follows,

```
Option Explicit
Dim m_Id As Integer
Public Property Get Id() As String
    Id= m_Id 
End Property

Public Property Let Id(ByVal New_Id As String)
    m_Id = New_Id
    PropertyChanged "Id"
End Property
```

Comment: What if the param is named something other than Id?

Comment: The msgbox is not an error, but a warning, and I believe you must sign your ActiveX dll with a cert in the trusted publisher store on the computer for it to go away.

Answer (score 1):

Your ActiveX is not safe for scripting. See [Safe Initialization and Scripting for ActiveX Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The warning message disappeared after I did the following.

> 1. Start -> Run -> regedit
> 2. Go to
>      HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVer
>      sion\Internet Settings\Zones\0
> 3. Doubleclick 1201 and change the value to 0 (it was
>      probably 1)
> 4. Close Registry Editor